# stuck on bootloop due to installed xposed framework

Tags: cyanogenmod

i recently installed xposed framework on my X-TIGI A5 china smartphone and on restart got into a bootloop,i have tried on the custom recovery but it seems that my device does not have either twrp or cwmr..anyone help me restore my device??

Comment: If you haven't installed them then of course your phone won't have TWRP or CWM.

Answer (score -2):

You could try formatting your phone in stock recovery even if you don't have any custom recovery such as TWRP or CWM installed.

Comment: This won't work. Xposed is installed on `/system` which is left unaffected by a factory reset.

Comment: How did he gain root access without a custom recovery ?

Comment: @user2119, search 1-click root access on web.

Comment: Hmm intrestting ; well I use a galaxy,so I installed a custom recovery using Odin and then only rooted my phone